# Trying to develop Chrome Extension for freely changing TimeZone, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, timezone, timezone-offset

I am deveoloping chrome-extension.
I want to change TimeZone of Chrome web page, but I cannot.

My code is for overriding web-pages javascript Date Objects.
When I put this code (web-accessible-resources) inside page context, the page's timezone change to 'Etc/Greenwich'.

I want to freely set the arguments saved at chrome-storage and change the pages timezone,
but I don't know what to do.

Can anyone give me some advice?

***web-accessible-resources***

```
(function (o) {
  const convertToGMT = function (n) {
    const format = function (v) {return (v < 10 ? '0' : '') + v};
    return (n <= 0 ? '+' : '-') + format(Math.abs(n) / 60 | 0) + format(Math.abs(n) % 60);
  };
  //
  const resolvedOptions = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions();
  const {
    toJSON, getYear, getMonth, getHours, toString, getMinutes, getSeconds, getUTCMonth, getFullYear, getUTCHours,
    getUTCFullYear, getMilliseconds, getTimezoneOffset, getUTCMilliseconds, toLocaleTimeString, toLocaleDateString,
    toISOString, toGMTString, toUTCString, toTimeString, toDateString, getUTCSeconds, getUTCMinutes, toLocaleString,
    getDay, getUTCDate, getUTCDay, getDate
  } = Date.prototype;
  //
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, '_offset', {'configurable': true, get() {return getTimezoneOffset.call(this)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, '_date', {'configurable': true, get() {
    return this._nd !== undefined ? this._nd : new Date(this.getTime() + (this._offset - o.value) * 60 * 1000);
  }});
  //
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toJSON', {"value": function () {return toJSON.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getDay', {"value": function () {return getDay.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getDate', {"value": function () {return getDate.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getYear', {"value": function () {return getYear.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getTimezoneOffset', {"value": function () {return Number(o.value)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getMonth', {"value": function () {return getMonth.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getHours', {"value": function () {return getHours.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCDay', {"value": function () {return getUTCDay.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCDate', {"value": function () {return getUTCDate.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getMinutes', {"value": function () {return getMinutes.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getSeconds', {"value": function () {return getSeconds.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCMonth', {"value": function () {return getUTCMonth.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCHours', {"value": function () {return getUTCHours.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getFullYear', {"value": function () {return getFullYear.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toISOString', {"value": function () {return toISOString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toGMTString', {"value": function () {return toGMTString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toUTCString', {"value": function () {return toUTCString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toDateString', {"value": function () {return toDateString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toTimeString', {"value": function () {return toTimeString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCSeconds', {"value": function () {return getUTCSeconds.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCMinutes', {"value": function () {return getUTCMinutes.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCFullYear', {"value": function () {return getUTCFullYear.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleString', {"value": function () {return toLocaleString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getMilliseconds', {"value": function () {return getMilliseconds.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'getUTCMilliseconds', {"value": function () {return getUTCMilliseconds.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleTimeString', {"value": function () {return toLocaleTimeString.call(this._date)}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleDateString', {"value": function () {return toLocaleDateString.call(this._date)}});
  //
  Object.defineProperty(Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype, 'resolvedOptions', {"value": function () {return Object.assign(resolvedOptions, {"timeZone": o.name})}});
  Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'toString', {'value': function () {
    return toString.call(this._date).replace(convertToGMT(this._offset), convertToGMT(o.value)).replace(/\(.*\)/, '(' + o.name.replace(/\//g, ' ') + ' Standard Time)');
  }});
  //
  document.documentElement.dataset.ctzscriptallow = true;
})({'name':'Etc/Greenwich','value':0})
```

****content-scripts****

```
let s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('change-timezone.js');

s.onload = function() {
  this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Can anyone give me some advice?*

Yes, I can:  **This is difficult.**

- The *idea* of a Chrome extension to change the time zone is a good one.  I personally would love this extension.  However, it is *not* a trivial endeavor.  The amount of code you will need to write is much larger than can fit in a StackOverflow question.  I suggest you start a GitHub project and find collaborators.  You may be able to get help on StackOverflow with specific questions, but not likely for the entire project.  It's just too broad.
- In your code, where you do this:

  ```
  new Date(this.getTime() + (this._offset - o.value) * 60 * 1000)
  ```

  That looks like an attempt to change the time zone, but it is critical you understand that it does not.  What it does instead is change the timestamp embedded in the date object.  That doesn't change the time zone, *it sets a different point in time*.
- That approach is called "Epoch Shifting", and it is used internally by libraries such as Moment.js and others.  They can use this technique because of three things:

  1. The shifted `Date` object is used only internally and never directly exposed to the end-user.
  2. The local-time based functions on the shifted `Date` object (such as `getHours` or `toString`) are never used once the object has been shifted.  Only the UTC-based functions (such as `getUTCHours` or `toISOString`) are used.
  3. The offset chosen to shift by is the one *after* conversion, not before.  This gets complicated, but matters near transitions.  Unit tests can reveal the challenge here.
- Epoch Shifting is commonly presented as a solution to time zone problems, but this is naive when one considers how the `Date` object works. Primarily, keep in mind that the timestamp in the `Date` object is *always* interpreted as UTC both externally and by the other functions in the `Date` object.  Also, the local time zone that is used by the `Date` object comes directly from the underlying native code (usually through OS-specific functions) and is not exposed into JavaScript for modification.
- In other words, one there is no JavaScript code that can change the time zone that the `Date` object uses.  Epoch Shifting is only a valid approach when all three of the above points are met.  It should generally be avoided in user code.
- Besides the `Date` object's functions, you'd also have to find a way to override `Intl.DateTimeFormat` such that the default resolved time zone is the one you are setting.
- With any approach, you'll need to have access to time zone data.  You could bring your own (such as Moment-Timezone does), or you could try to pull it from the Intl object (such as Luxon does).